# Assigning a hyperlink to <p></p> in html

Tags: html

I want to assign a hyperlink to the `<p>Click here</p>` format, however when i do it

```
<p href="http://www.ironspider.ca/format_text/hyperlinks.htm">
  Creating Hyperlinks
</p>
```

The hyperlink does not show up.

Comment: Where did ever see `<p>` with an `href`? Even the most basic, dated, error-ridden HTML tutorial will teach you how to properly make a link, I'm baffled by this question.

Comment: @WesleyMurch - "Where did ever see <p> with an href?". The now defunct XHTML 2.0 allowed this.

Comment: @Alohci: `<reply rel="comment" mood="intrigued">Interesting</reply>`

Answer (score 2):

yes

```
  <p href="http://www.ironspider.ca/format_text/hyperlinks.htm">Creating Hyperlinks</p>
```

change to

```
 <a href="http://www.ironspider.ca/format_text/hyperlinks.htm">Creating Hyperlinks</a>
```

that question made me smile, gotta start somewhere!

Answer (score 1):

The `<p>` element does not take an `href` attribute. If you want a link, add an additional `<a>` tag.